# create File supporting UTF-8

Tags: java, file, csv, utf-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to write a UTF-8 file with Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001540/how-to-write-a-utf-8-file-with-java)

I want to create a csv file using java and write into it which supporting UTF-8.
How can I do this.?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001540/how-to-write-a-utf-8-file-with-java

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("path/to/file"), Charset.forName("UTF-8"))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Writer myWriter= new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
    new FileOutputStream("filename"), "UTF-8"));
try {
    myWriter.write(stringdata);
} catch(Exception e){
e.printStacktrace();
}
```