# Output data in UTF-8 format

Tags: utf-8

I am having difficulty outputting data in UTF-8 format.  I have a test case set up where data I am reading from an input file contains a British pound symbol (Hex C2A3).  When I write it out on Linux, I get valid UTF-8 (C2A3).  On windows, I only get HEX A3.

I tried using a PrintStream and specifying the character set as "UTF-8".  No luck.  I tried many other streams with no luck until I finally tried a DataOutputStream.  I used the "write()" method which took a byte array as a parameter.  I needed to output a string, so I called "myString.getBytes("UTF-8")".

I ended up with code like:

dataOutputStream.write(myString.getBytes("UTF-8"));

This works properly on both systems; Windows 7 and Linux.

I am trying to understand why this worked and convince myself my solution is correct.  Does it come down to system Locale's?  Linux defaults to en_US.utf-8.  While all I could specify in Windows was just "en_US".  So when the outputstream attempted to get data from the string, the string was sending its data based upon the locale?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or are you using FileOutputStream and there it matters the character encoding or DataOutputStream where you write binary. You should do a research too, but look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001540/how-to-write-a-utf-8-file-with-java) please

Comment: Thanks.  It was the OutputStreamWriter I was missing.  I was stuck on using a PrintWriter and specifying the charset there, but that just wasn't working.