# How do I store the Unicode text in a file, after I get it from the database?

Tags: java, file, unicode

Inside the database table there is a file named `♥-You-Got-Me-♥[www.savevid.com].mp4`. I need to get the name of this file and save it in text file. But the way I am saving,I see `?` instead of `♥`.How do I store text in Unicode ?

The way I am doing is :

```
String name = Foo.getNameFromTheTable();
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(file);
writer.println(name);
writer.close();
```

But this doesn't store the text in unicode form.

Answer (score 1):

From [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#print%28java.lang.String%29):

> Prints a string. If the argument is null then the string "null" is printed. Otherwise, the string's characters are converted into bytes according to the platform's **default character encoding**, and these bytes are written in exactly the manner of the write(int) method.

That's the reason of problem.

Instead, use `FileOutputStream` and `OutputStreamWriter`:

```
OutputStreamWriter(OutputStream out, String charsetName) 
Create an OutputStreamWriter that uses the named charset.
```

See solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1001568/1360074

Comment: I still get `?` instead of hearts

Comment: @SuhailGupta What is encoding of database table? Are you able to debug with Eclipse and make sure that line retrieved from database has correct encoding and gets spoiled only when writing to a file?

Comment: The table accepts the data as Unicode. I am using MS SQL and the data type for that column is `NVARCHAR`