# UTF-8 encoding issue special characters like 'É' not replicated properly

Tags: java, string

I am trying to encode a string with special characters like 'É' using below mentioned code then it is not replicated properly...

```
String Cdata="MARIE-HÉLÈNE";
byte sByte[]=Cdata.getBytes(); 
Cdata= new String(sByte,"UTF-8");
System.out.println(Cdata);
```

expected output: MARIE-HÉLÈNE but instead output: MARIE-HE coming

Comment: even tried using :byte sByte[]=Cdata.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"); 
Still getting same output

Comment: Is your Java file encoded in UTF-8?

Comment: How do i excatly encode entire java file in UTF-8

Comment: Check config of your IDE or text editor.

Comment: Where are you looking at the output ? Can you please try writing the content in a file instead. Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001540/how-to-write-a-utf-8-file-with-java for writing in file

Comment: @saury : I am using RAD IDE and used a core java class for this System.out.println command will show output of this on console.

Answer (score 2):

First thing is that you need to make sure that your source file is actually stored as `UTF-8` - see @Ankur's answer for a good explanation.

Then, you also need to provide an encoding when calling `getBytes()` on `String` to retrieve the byte array:

```
byte sByte[] = Cdata.getBytes("UTF-8");
```

If you call `String.getBytes()` with no encoding, the **platform`s default encoding** is used, which can be (almost) anything. See also [java.lang.String.getBytes()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes%28%29):

> Encodes this String into a sequence of bytes using the platform's default charset

With that, the following SSCCE properly prints the expected output for me (note: took identifiers from question, not adjusted to coding conventions):

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

public class Encoding {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
      String Cdata = "MARIE-HÉLÈNE";
      byte sByte[] = Cdata.getBytes("UTF-8"); 
      Cdata = new String(sByte,"UTF-8");
      System.out.println(Cdata);
   }
}
```

Comment: HI Andreas, I have tried this piece of code it although produces right output but when i wrap this string and send to other webservice for replication of output bytes they replicate it incorrectly as MARIE-H?L?N ... and reported that i ma not encoding it properly.. can you please specify that that if i am encoding properly or they are decoding it incorrectly

Comment: You might need to set also some encoding when transferring the string through the web service - it looks as if the string is transferred as ISO8859-1 or something through the web service. But we would need to know more about the web service framework you are using - I suggest that you ask a new question if you can not manage to make it work

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell eclipse to use UTF-8 for its stdout console. You can set that by Window > Preferences > General > Workspace > Text File Encoding.

[image]

Comment: `You need to tell eclipse to use UTF-8 for its stdout console` - the important thing is that you are setting the **source file format** to UTF-8 (which you do as you describe), so that the respective characters are properly stored in the source file

Comment: Hi Ankur I am getting this output: MARIE-H�L�NE