# How to write file UTF8?

Tags: java, utf-8

I think I need to use

```
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(fileName), "UTF8"));
```

But when I change my code to BufferedWriter, then something is wrong with the line `out.write(e);`.

My code:

```
public void writeToFile(String fileName, List<ThongtinKhachThue> resultttkt){
        System.out.println("Begin....");
        try {
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new File(fileName));
            out.println("//thue.txt");
            for(ThongtinKhachThue e : resultttkt){
                    out.println(e);                 
            }
            out.println("Tổng khách thuê phòng: "+TongKhachThue());
            out.println("Tổng tiền thu: "+TongTienThuDuoc()+"$");
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            System.out.println("End...");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

what it shows in file:

```
//thue.txt
K1, A1002, 47.05$ 
K2, A0003, 67.0$ 
K3, A1001, 31.0$ 
K4, null, 0.0$ 
T?ng khách thuê ph?ng: 3
T?ng ti?n thu: 145.05$
```

what I want it to show is:

```
//thue.txt
K1, A1002, 47.05$ 
K2, A0003, 67.0$ 
K3, A1001, 31.0$ 
K4, Không thuê
Tổng khách thuê: 03
Tổng tiền thu: 145.05$
```

How can i write utf-8 to file and change "3" to "03"?

Comment: Yes, you need to use BufferedWriter.

Comment: This is possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001540/how-to-write-a-utf-8-file-with-java/1001562#1001562

Comment: what do you mean by "then something is wrong with the line out.write(e);"?

Comment: Don't forget to read UTF-8 files using UTF-8 encoding.  If you use windows encoding for example, it will read files with windows encoding correctly.

Answer (score 3):

To write `03` (leading zero) instead of `3` you can use

```
int myInteger = 3;
out.println("Some value: " + String.format("%02d", myInteger) );
```

See [String.format(...) documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) for details on the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Use,

```
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(path),"UTF-8"));
```

that way you can set the encoding.

Comment: no... they are doing PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new File(fileName));

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the charset names mentioned at this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html)

It says the standard charsets as "UTF-8" and not "UTF8".

So change it to "UTF-8" and it will work.

Below for your reference :

- **US-ASCII**
                                            Seven-bit ASCII, a.k.a. ISO646-US, a.k.a. the Basic Latin
  block of the Unicode character set
- **ISO-8859-1**
  ISO Latin Alphabet
  No. 1, a.k.a. ISO-LATIN-1
- **UTF-8**
  Eight-bit UCS Transformation Format
- **UTF-16BE**
  Sixteen-bit UCS Transformation Format, big-endian byte order
- **UTF-16LE**
  Sixteen-bit UCS Transformation Format, little-endian byte
  order
- **UTF-16**
  Sixteen-bit UCS Transformation Format, byte order
  identified by an optional byte-order mark

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Writer out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
    new FileOutputStream("outfilename"), "UTF-8"));
try {
    out.write(aString);
} finally {
    out.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you already know that you should use a BufferedWriter since it let's you chose the encoding I do not see what's the problem here.

I would only like to add that instead of writing "UTF8" as a string which is error prone you can use, as of Java 1.7, the class [StandardCharsets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html) to get, well, all the standard charsets :-)

If Java 1.7 isn't an option you can also use Guava's [Charsets](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Charsets.html) class.