# Writing to a file with accented char

Tags: java, file, encoding, bufferedwriter

I'm using something like this in a java application to write to a file:

```
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(out1, true)); //where out1 is a File.
```

When I run it from netBeans the output is good. When I try to run it from the windows command line (the intended use; using the jar) the accented characters go crazy. I think that is have something to do with the chars encoding.

e.g.
(the output file is a HTML one);

I want to write this:

```
"<p>Inclinação(1):</p>"
```

Using Win command line, appears this:

```
<p>Inclina褯(1):</p>
```

Comment: How are you writing your String to the `BufferedWriter out`? You may have an encoding issue, or you may have a console font issue.

Comment: I'm using out.write("...");

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001540/how-to-write-a-utf-8-file-with-java

Answer (score 1):

Use `OutputStreamWriter` with `FileOutputStream` so you can explicitly specify the Charset.

```
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(out1, true), "UTF-8"));
```

Comment: I will give it a try. btw, what is the better charset to use with accented chars and compatible with HTML 4.01 Transitional ?

Comment: Pretty much always stick with `utf-8`, unless you have a specific reason not to. I do believe that the default in 4 is `iso-8859-1` (HTML5 is `utf-8`), so you should add a `meta` charset declaration.

Comment: Using your option, I'm not able to write to the next line without using .newLine() ; My entire app is using "\n" with strings that I write.

Comment: Not sure what you mean... you're using `write`, so: `out.write("foo\n");`. `println()`, `newLine()`, etc. are system-dependent (hence the difference between NetBeans and Windows shell), so that's probably not what you want to begin with.

Comment: So, what is the best way to do print with that specs ?

Comment: Just that: `out.write("foo\n");`

Comment: I'm using this right now: BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("oi.txt", true), "ISO-8859-15"));
                out.write("oi\n");
        out.write("yes");        out.close();

Comment: And the output is(after I runned the teste a few times):

"oi
yesoi
yesoi
yesoi
yesoi
yesoi
yesoi
yes"

Comment: how are you viewing the output?

Comment: I was viewing the wrong file, sorry mate. It has been a long day ,eheh.

Thanks, a lot. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you need to specify an encoding, unfortunately `FileWriter` does not provide any ways to set it, though there are other options such as:

```
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter
    (new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(out1, true),"UTF-8"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this problem using the parameter 8859_1, you can learn more about here
http://www.cafeconleche.org/books/xmljava/chapters/ch03s03.html.

```
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(baos, "8859_1"));
```