# String.replace not Working

Tags: java, string, replace

I have a string in my maven project and when I run it on my local machine, I have

```
String name = title.get(i).text().replace("é", "e");
```

Later I save the variable `name` to a file

But then when I export to .jar and run the it on my server I see é not e, but when I run on my local machine I see "e" which is what I want.

What is happening?

Comment: What is the type of `title`?

Comment: I don't think you've given enough information to answer this question. It probably has something to do with the platform's default charset or file encoding, and nothing to do with `String.replace`.

Comment: @ChrisMartin when you say platform you mean the server I am trying to run it on?, but it runs normal java how would it not do replace?

Comment: @spenf10 try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001540/how-to-write-a-utf-8-file-with-java/1001568#1001568) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001540/how-to-write-a-utf-8-file-with-java/1001982#1001982)

Comment: Where are the text values coming from?  I wonder if perhaps your strings contain the single character `'\u00e9'` when you run the program locally, whereas the strings on your server contain the sequence `'\u0065\u0301'`.  If that's the case, you can create a [Matcher](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) outside your loop using `Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("e", Pattern.CANON_EQ).matcher("");`, and inside your loop, you can do `String name = matcher.reset(title.get(i).text()).replaceAll("e");`.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to change that from a web page you may want to try:

```
String name = title.get(i).text().replace("%C3%A9", "e");
```