# Creating file from data stored in xml

Tags: java, file, streamwriter

I really don't know how to describe this properly. I have a XML file with files in following format (it's a part of a jpg file):

```
mF1vmzAUhu8n7T8g307gpNu6bgrpxT6u9lGp3Q/w4JBYA9uynSz59ztA0pKKFFpj+SaKP973PBZg
v/LieleV0Ra04VKkZJ7MSAQikzkXq5T8vvsWX5HIWCZyVkoBKdmDIdfL168Wd3sFJkK1MClZW6s+
UWqyNVTMJFKBwJFC6opZbOoVVSz7y1ZAL2azS5pJYUHY2NYeZLn4AgXblDb6usPulkSJFYk+t/Pq
UinhVa2v+2mvAqqiV7GL65F+jYbSPBIxpUqeMYvjdCvyR2uJD+tIUNnMMWuuzBuccKZCPXK+wEH3
Cx+A5jlEN0zbn6zCWVQpS5UGg7pmbvK0Uw+qLAqeQS6zTYWSpGtWlSfNpGJcHBdxDsaU2PmDGYsv
S7cxn5qs4z2K6UDjh+M5BBfBCd4GJ3gXnOB9cILL4AQfghNcBSf4GJxgPguPEGZXFNKCOZ4Vncbk
NB3vIaY1hhi5sUeqk+bkXCfuQ2S19kZLZXyc8Y3xEMGWwz8vBPfGQwQWkyO0v+4Po7EZrMj+lHBr
9yVMvuqO9aiP9Tvb48ty+GTbhp/vtvV+KZOffOPG5CfxuDH5yUBuTH5SkRuTn5zkxuQnObkx+clS
bkx+0pUbk6e85QgVcifvnKrum/e4U/WhovvWPKpiEwFv28z78N9P0mysXwY0+eE5DgjVTf6imdTw
fITjdVetjhUagbb86VRzXxGtndcM9U1aDnlPbdrcQC7/AwAA//8DAFBLAwQUAAYACAAAACEA82vR
hfEAAABRAgAACwAIAl9yZWxzLy5yZWxzIKIEAiigAAIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAKySz0oDMRCH74LvEObenW0FEWm2FxF6E1kf
YEhm/+BuMiSjtG9vFEQXaunBYya/+fLNkO3uME/mnVMeY7CwrmowHFz0Y+gtvLSPqzswWSl4mmJg
```

What is this "format" called (I need to google properly)? I tried to copy this text into a textfile and naming it "MyPicture.jpg", but I couldn't open it. Isn't it possible to retrieve a file like that? Do I have to change the encoding?

In the next step I wanna use a StreamWriter using java, to restore the files. Anything that I have to take care of, by doing that?

Comment: It looks like base64 data. You might be able to decode it with `Base64.getDecoder()` and get more meaningful bytes data.

Comment: This is neither an XML nor a JPG file. It looks like it is base64-encoded though...

Comment: I didn't post the xml, just the "attachement" tag, which is a file. It's base64, so now that I know that, I can decode it, using java (already decoded it on a website and I was able to get the jpg)

Thanks a lot, now I know how to keep going!

Answer (score 1):

Most likely base64 content, so try this and ensure you copy all of the data into the `base64Content` variable...

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

String base64Content = "mF1vmzAUhu8n7T8g307gpNu6bgrpxT6u9lGp3Q/w4JBYA9uynSz5 ... ";
String decodedContent = IOUtils.toString(Base64.decodeBase64(base64Content.getBytes()), "UTF-8");
```

If the `decodedContent` is not readable, you may have a binary file (e.g MS Word,image etc). Usually looking at the binary file you can tell what it is. If not look at using [Apache Tika](https://tika.apache.org/)

When writing the data back out just ensure you use UTF-8 again. See [how-to-write-a-utf-8-file-with-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001540/how-to-write-a-utf-8-file-with-java)